# Using && for conditionals in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
var field = query("form#"+form.id+" input[name='" + error.field + "']");
if(field.length){
  if( field[0].id ) {
    widget = registry.byId( field[0].id );
    if(widget){
    ...
  }
 }
```

I would have thought I could write:

```
var field = query("form#"+form.id+" input[name='" + error.field + "']");
if(field.length && field[0].id && widget = registry.byId( field[0].id) ){
...
}
```

But if I use the second, "shortened" form, I get a Javascript error.

Sorry, it would be messy to give a JSFiddle. The problem happens when query() returns 0 values  -- `field[0].id` && `widget = registry.byId( field[0].id)`  were still interpreted.

I thought that I was playing it safe as the second `field[0].id` would only happen if `field.length` was `> 0` and then `widget =  registry.byId( field[0].id)` would only happen if `field[0].id`  is true...

What am I missing?

Merc.

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: A live example would be useful too (on jsfiddle), but knowing what the error you get is is the most important thing right now.

Comment: Sorry, I clarified the question. And, there is an answer -- the missing brackets!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` error which is because you are trying to evaluate `registry.byId()` method on RIGHT and assigning it into `result` on LEFT but as you've not restricted your left-hand assignment using brackets, the entire `field.length && field[0].id && widget` is considered which raised an error.

You can suppress the error by wrapping your last condition in brackets.
`if(field.length && field[0].id && (widget = registry.byId( field[0].id)) ){`

Comment: You were absolutely right -- the problem was in the missing brackets around the last condition. If wasn't there, and as a result all three were being evaluated as l-values. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `=` operator has a lower precendence than the `&&` operator, so your code is trying to take the result of:

```
field.length && field[0].id && widget
```

...and assign a value to it. You can work around this by putting parentheses around the assignment:

```
if(field.length && field[0].id && (widget = registry.byId(field[0].id)) ){
```

(Seems to then work fine in this little demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/4dAfS/)

Further reading: [MDN's Operator Precedence article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)